# what is the criteria to adjust the propertires of pooling conenction

Tags: java, oracle, connection-pooling

how can i adjust the properties of connection pooling like

```
setMaxPoolSize();
setMaxIdleTime();
setMaxPoolSize();
setMinPoolSize();
setInitialPoolSize();
setPropertyCycle();
setMaxStatements();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on traffic to your database, time that expend your queries... several factors. This is a shared resource for your application you need a complete photo of your scenario to set the right value to get the better performance.

Hope this link help you: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3681/abehq?a=view